# Unity open door using tags

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in unity I have a key that triggers using this

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Door_01"))
    {
       other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

And I have a door using the tags door_01_left and door_01_right

How can I use something like this to open the door when the player gets the key using the tag?

```
transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, 30, 0));
```

I know is not the best way to do this, but can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("door_01_left") || other.gameObject.CompareTag("door_01_right"))
{
   other.transform.Rotate(new Vector3 (0, 30, 0));
}
```

However it’d seem more sensible to just tag them all as “door” and *name* them door_01_left or whatever.

Getting the doors to open smoothly and stop rotating at a specific point is a separate task.

Comment: Thats the problem, After I get the key, the doors should open automatically. This will not work:

 `private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Door_01")) 
        { 
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);

   if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("door_01_left") || other.gameObject.CompareTag("door_01_right")){

        transform.Rotate(new Vector3 (100, 100, 0));
   }
  }
    }`

Comment: In the code you pasted, the CompareTag("door_01_left") part will never be reached because it’s inside the CompareTag("Door_01") *if* clause. I really suggest you just use one tag name for this stuff at least until you have the current problem solved so as to avoid this confusion. Another thing is that OnTriggerEnter is only called if one of the two colliders is set as a trigger, so you may want to check that that’s the case.

Comment: But if i use the same tag for both doors and for the key, the doors will open to opposite sides right? Like door left will turn 30 degress and open properly, but door right will open in the opposite direction. The key is a trigger, yes

Comment: If they’re not moving at all currently, get them moving first and worry about getting them moving in the right direction afterwards. You can try removing the `if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Door_01"))` line first if you prefer and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Lol, I understood how scripts work now, sorry. I see how i cant rotate it now

Comment: Thank you for the help, i am going with animations, and even tho it did not help in this situation, it made me realize other way of using scripts, thank you very much

Comment: Yes that sounds like a better idea. I didn’t suggest alternatives since you said “I know is not the best way to do this, but can be done?”